# Cleaning CSV file with python skips certain rows

Tags: python-3.x, csv, data-cleaning

I have data in a `csv`-file of the form

```
karthiga, 21, 9,
karthiga, 59, 7,
karthiga, 74, 7,
karthiga, 120, 7,
karthiga, 178, 7,
karthiga, 210, 7,
karthiga, 232, 6,
karthiga, 233, 6,
karthiga, 249, 8,
karthiga, 269, 10,
karthiga, 721, 7,
karthiga, 853, 7,
karthiga, 857, 10,
karthiga, 11123, 7,
karthiga, 11759, 5,
karthiga, 12365, 8,
karthiga, 14227, 8,
karthiga, 14397, 7,
karthiga, 14713, 10,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 1, 8,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 16, 4,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 19, 9,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 228, 5,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 237, 7,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 239, 7,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 245, 8,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 251, 4,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 268, 9,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 269, 6,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 270, 4,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 323, 7,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 777, 3,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 849, 5,
"
, , ,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 853, 9,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 877, 8,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 885, 5,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 934, 8,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 936, 7,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 1210, 9,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 1216, 6,
"
, , ,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 1412, 9,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 1425, 10,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 1535, 10,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 1562, 3,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 1575, 10,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 1639, 8,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 1686, 7,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 1689, 4,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 1698, 8,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 1735, 9,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 1829, 8,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 1887, 6,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 1953, 6,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 9479, 3,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 9587, 5,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 9656, 6,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 9675, 8,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 9756, 9,
"
, , ,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 9919, 6,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 9926, 10,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 9989, 5,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 10020, 8,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 10029, 10,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 34599, 10,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 34612, 9,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 34636, 7,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 34712, 7,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 34822, 5,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 34881, 6,
RedvelvetDaisuki, 34902, 7,
Damonashu, 272, 8,
Damonashu, 274, 7,
Damonashu, 298, 4,
Damonashu, 317, 6,
Damonashu, 323, 9,
Damonashu, 335, 5,
Damonashu, 339, 6,
Damonashu, 387, 7,
```

I would like to remove all the rows with only `"` or `, , ,` in them. So, I wrote a little python script to do this

```
from csv import reader

with open("file.csv") as read_obj:
    csv_reader = reader(read_obj)

    for row in csv_reader:
        row = row[:-1]
        if len(row) == 3 and row[0] != '':
            print(row)
```

which prints out

```
['karthiga', ' 21', ' 9']
['karthiga', ' 59', ' 7']
['karthiga', ' 74', ' 7']
['karthiga', ' 120', ' 7']
['karthiga', ' 178', ' 7']
['karthiga', ' 210', ' 7']
['karthiga', ' 232', ' 6']
['karthiga', ' 233', ' 6']
['karthiga', ' 249', ' 8']
['karthiga', ' 269', ' 10']
['karthiga', ' 721', ' 7']
['karthiga', ' 853', ' 7']
['karthiga', ' 857', ' 10']
['karthiga', ' 11123', ' 7']
['karthiga', ' 11759', ' 5']
['karthiga', ' 12365', ' 8']
['karthiga', ' 14227', ' 8']
['karthiga', ' 14397', ' 7']
['karthiga', ' 14713', ' 10']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', ' 1', ' 8']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', ' 16', ' 4']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', ' 19', ' 9']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', ' 228', ' 5']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', ' 237', ' 7']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', ' 239', ' 7']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', ' 245', ' 8']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', ' 251', ' 4']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', ' 268', ' 9']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', ' 269', ' 6']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', ' 270', ' 4']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', ' 323', ' 7']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', ' 777', ' 3']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', ' 849', ' 5']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', ' 1412', ' 9']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', ' 1425', ' 10']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', ' 1535', ' 10']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', ' 1562', ' 3']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', ' 1575', ' 10']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', ' 1639', ' 8']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', ' 1686', ' 7']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', ' 1689', ' 4']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', ' 1698', ' 8']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', ' 1735', ' 9']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', ' 1829', ' 8']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', ' 1887', ' 6']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', ' 1953', ' 6']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', ' 9479', ' 3']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', ' 9587', ' 5']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', ' 9656', ' 6']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', ' 9675', ' 8']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', ' 9756', ' 9']
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea why it stops midway... There are more entries after the last one it prints, but for some reason, it just stops without giving me any kind of error or anything... Can somebody explain to me what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opted to have the code print out each row before processing it, so we could see exactly what was read in by the csv_reader.

Because of the way that csv_reader parses commas, newlines, etc, we end up getting some anomalous results. I am showing those results for the line with RedvelvetDaisuki, 9756, 9, (and the line after it) but we also get similar results at the other gaps in the data.

```
['RedvelvetDaisuki', ' 9675', ' 8', '']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', ' 9756', ' 9', '']
['\n, , ,\nRedvelvetDaisuki, 9919, 6,\nRedvelvetDaisuki, 9926, 10,\nRedvelvetDaisuki, 9989, 5,\nRedvelvetDaisuki, 10020, 8,\nRedvelvetDaisuki, 10029, 10,\nRedvelvetDaisuki, 34599, 10,\nRedvelvetDaisuki, 34612, 9,\nRedvelvetDaisuki, 34636, 7,\nRedvelvetDaisuki, 34712, 7,\nRedvelvetDaisuki, 34822, 5,\nRedvelvetDaisuki, 34881, 6,\nRedvelvetDaisuki, 34902, 7,\nDamonashu, 272, 8,\nDamonashu, 274, 7,\nDamonashu, 298, 4,\nDamonashu, 317, 6,\nDamonashu, 323, 9,\nDamonashu, 335, 5,\nDamonashu, 339, 6,\nDamonashu, 387, 7,']
```

A technique to get around this might be to parse the data and strip out all rows that have anomalous data without using the csv_reader at all:

```
open("file.csv") as read_obj: 
    for line in read_obj: 
        if '"' in line or ', , ,' in line: 
            continue 
        else: 
            line = line.strip().replace(',', '').split(' ') 
            print(line)
```

Which yields:

```
['karthiga', '21', '9']
['karthiga', '59', '7']
['karthiga', '74', '7']
['karthiga', '120', '7']
['karthiga', '178', '7']
['karthiga', '210', '7']
['karthiga', '232', '6']
['karthiga', '233', '6']
['karthiga', '249', '8']
['karthiga', '269', '10']
['karthiga', '721', '7']
['karthiga', '853', '7']
['karthiga', '857', '10']
['karthiga', '11123', '7']
['karthiga', '11759', '5']
['karthiga', '12365', '8']
['karthiga', '14227', '8']
['karthiga', '14397', '7']
['karthiga', '14713', '10']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '1', '8']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '16', '4']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '19', '9']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '228', '5']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '237', '7']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '239', '7']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '245', '8']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '251', '4']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '268', '9']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '269', '6']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '270', '4']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '323', '7']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '777', '3']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '849', '5']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '853', '9']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '877', '8']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '885', '5']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '934', '8']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '936', '7']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '1210', '9']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '1216', '6']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '1412', '9']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '1425', '10']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '1535', '10']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '1562', '3']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '1575', '10']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '1639', '8']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '1686', '7']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '1689', '4']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '1698', '8']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '1735', '9']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '1829', '8']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '1887', '6']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '1953', '6']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '9479', '3']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '9587', '5']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '9656', '6']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '9675', '8']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '9756', '9']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '9919', '6']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '9926', '10']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '9989', '5']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '10020', '8']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '10029', '10']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '34599', '10']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '34612', '9']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '34636', '7']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '34712', '7']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '34822', '5']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '34881', '6']
['RedvelvetDaisuki', '34902', '7']
['Damonashu', '272', '8']
['Damonashu', '274', '7']
['Damonashu', '298', '4']
['Damonashu', '317', '6']
['Damonashu', '323', '9']
['Damonashu', '335', '5']
['Damonashu', '339', '6']
['Damonashu', '387', '7']
```

Comment: That is not an anomalous result at all. In the CSV specification, the value of one cell can be a string containing commas and newlines if it's enclosed in quotes.

Comment: Also, it's a better idea to split on `", "` instead of replacing the commas and splitting on spaces, because the latter would break if there were legitimate spaces in the data.